# Please, I need to create an image in my Latex but it doesn't work for me?

Tags: graphics, errors, pstricks

Please I don't know why it's not working for me, I get a lot of errors!!
like

```
! Undefined control sequence.\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format \psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}
```

```
 \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}}



\newcommand{\foo}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\scri}{\scriptsize}



\numberwithin{equation}{section}





\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist} % The distance.




\begin{document}


\begin{abstract}
***
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
**

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(16,8)%\psgrid
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,2)(14,2)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2,1)(2,7)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](3,2)(3,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](4,2)(4,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](5,2)(5,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](6,2)(6,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](7,2)(7,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](8,2)(8,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](11,2)(11,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](13,2)(13,4)
\pscircle*[](2,3.6){0.07cm}     \pscircle*[](4,4){0.07cm}
\pscircle*[](5,3.4){0.07cm}     \pscircle*[](6,3.6){0.07cm}
\pscircle*[](7,4){0.07cm}       \pscircle*[](8,3.6){0.07cm}
\pscircle*[](13,4){0.07cm}
\pscurve[]{->}(2,3.6)(2.4,3.8)(2.6,3.6)(3,4)
\pscurve[]{->}(4,4)(3.6,3.6)(3.4,3.7)(3,3.4)
\pscurve[]{->}(5,3.4)(4.6,3.6)(4.2,3.4)(4,3.3)
\pscurve[]{->}(6,3.6)(5.6,3.8)(5.4,3.7)(5,4)
\pscurve[]{->}(7,4)(6.6,4.1)(6.4,3.8)(6,4)
\pscurve[]{->}(8,3.6)(7.6,3.8)(7.4,3.7)(7,3.6)
\pscurve[]{->}(13,4)(12.2,3.6)(11.6,3.8)(11,3.6)
\psline*[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=green](2,1.8)(3,1.8)(3,2.2)(2,2.2)
\psline*[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=green](4,1.8)(5,1.8)(5,2.2)(4,2.2)
\psline*[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=green](6,1.8)(7,1.8)(7,2.2)(6,2.2)
\psline*[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=green](11,1.8)(13,1.8)(13,2.2)(11,2.2)
\psline[fillstyle=solid,fillstyle=vlines](3,1.8)(4,1.8)(4,2.2)(3,2.2)
\psline[fillstyle=solid,fillstyle=vlines](5,1.8)(6,1.8)(6,2.2)(5,2.2)
\psline[fillstyle=solid,fillstyle=vlines](7,1.8)(8,1.8)(8,2.2)(7,2.2)
\pscurve[linestyle=dashed](3,4)(3.5,3.6)(4,3.4)(4.6,3.6)(5,3.4)(5.4,3.6)
(5.6,3.4)(6,4)(6.4,3.8)(6.6,4.1)(7,4)(7.6,3.8)(8,4)(9.6,3)(10.4,3.4)(11,3.6)
(11.6,3.8)(12.2,3.6)(13,4)
\rput(1.3,1.7){\foo $t_0=s_0$}       \rput(3,1.6){\foo $t_1$}
\rput(4,1.5){\foo $s_1$}             \rput(5,1.6){\foo $t_2$}
\rput(6,1.5){\foo $s_2$}             \rput(7,1.6){\foo $t_3$}
\rput(8,1.5){\foo $s_3$}             \rput(11,1.5){\foo $s_{i}$}
\rput(13,1.5){\foo $t_{i}=\tau$}
\rput(14.2,2){\foo $t$}              \rput(2,7.2){\foo $Z$}
\rput(9,1.6){\large $\dots$}         \rput(10,1.6){\large $\dots$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I get that:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and not part of a MWE. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also what kind of errors do you see and which LaTeX version are you using?

Comment: ok, I just edit my question I add all the code and I explain what kind of errors I get. Thank you.

Comment: You're probably compiling with `pdflatex`, whch has no computation engine. Try with, say, `xelatex` or try the traditional way `latex ->dvips->pstopdf`.

Comment: yes, you're right, when I have changed to Xelatex.
I have no more errors but the picture is not complete. Can you please help me!

Comment: Is it on purpose that the hatched rectangles are not closed?

Comment: I don't understand your question!!

Comment: The left side of the  rectangles with vlines does not exist. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: I just add an image to my initial question, to explain how it should be the image.

Comment: That's exactly what I obtain. What are you missing?

Comment: I just add an image to my question of what I get.

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary stuff from your example.  All of the blank lines, comments, and newcommands only make it harder to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I just edit my question again, I remove the unnecessary stuff from my Code. I also put an image of what I get.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get with `xelatex` or with `latex`-> `dvips`->`ps2pdf`:

[image]

Comment: I think I have a problem with my LaTex, It works for a friends of my and not for me!

Comment: Your error message stated that your editor uses `pdflatex`  and not `xelatex`